# SCCM 2007 Powershell "Update Collection Membership"

Tags: powershell, sccm-2007

Is there Powershell command/script that can be setup to run an "update collection memebership" on a specific collection and subcollections? If not Powershell another way besides right click on Collection and manually run an update collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it on regular basis using WMI.
Simple function that does it:

```
$YourSCCMServer = '?'
$YourSite = '?'

$WMIStatic = @{
    ComputerName = "$YourSCCMServer"
    NameSpace = "root\sms\site_$YourSite"
}

function Update-Collection {
param ($Filter)
Get-WmiObject @WMIStatic -Class SMS_Collection @PSBoundParameters |
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Name RequestRefresh
}

Update-Collection -Filter "CollectionID = 'SMS00001'"
```

You just need to fill in the blanks. And write a filter that would include collections you are after.

**EDIT**: Typo in namespace, not sure where first backslash came from. BTW: for list it's better to include wildcards: `-List Collection` would not return any results, `-List *Collection*` would.

Comment: Is this for PS V3.0?  I tried this Get-WmiObject @WMIStatic -Class *Collection* -List as your example but I get error Get-WmiObject : Invalid parameter. I checked Namespace and Computername is right.

Comment: It's not v3 in any way - that was just typo in Namespace, now fixed.

Comment: correct my test was using this - just left them off Get-WmiObject @WMIStatic -Class *Collection* -LIST (Yes, removing the \ was the issue)